# Geometry Node Proximity Shader Question

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, geometry-nodes, geometry

question in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sH8SovE4G-Q&t=1373s

the person was able to get colors on the cube without subdiving the cube and instead he was using vertex colors, and yes i know he was using blender version 2.93 version and that version has some unique node (Mainly Attribute Proximity Node)  and so here's the question

can you somehow replicate his way of using vertex colors instead on the version 3.0 or 3.2 ?

Comment: In the video it's an early Blender 3.0 alpha version, not 2.93. Have a look at the status bar in the video. The cube is subdivided 15 times (at 15:36) and at 17:06 you can see it in edit mode. Also, he uses different materials, not vertex colors. But indeed there is still the *Attribute Proximity* node used which is a 2.93 node. In Blender 3.0 with *Geometry Node Fields*, this node has been remade as *Geometry Proximity*.

Comment: As Blunder has already noted: The cube is subdivided several times in the example. Without subdivision this is not possible with Geometry Nodes. So please be so kind and edit your question.